# Not a JPEG file: Starts with 0x00 0x00

Tags: c, image, pointers, libjpeg

I am trying to read a working JPEG file with the jpeg-6b library with a wrapper made around that library.

When i have a dynamic image it works correctly but when i try to put one static image form a file, it don't work and show this error as Not a JPEG file: Starts with 0x00 0x00 and premature end of a file. I am not sure where is the issue but i think the issue lies in the image pointer I am passing. But I am trying to read the pointer values it prints the correct values as in the JPEG file.

Here is the code snippet

```
char *image_jpeg;
char *entries;
FILE *fd;
fd = fopen("abc.jpg", "r");
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(fd);
rewind(fd);

image_jpeg = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size);
fread(image_jpeg, file_size, 1, fd);
printf("file_size %d",file_size);
fclose(fd);


printf("%x\n", image_jpeg[0] & 0xff);
printf("%x\n", image_jpeg[1] & 0xff);
printf("%x\n", image_jpeg[2] & 0xff);
printf("%x\n", image_jpeg[3] & 0xff);

decompress_jpeg(&image_raw, &size_raw, &width, &height, &bpp, image_jpeg, file_size,jpeg_frac);
```

Here is the snippet of the decompress function which is working well with the dynamic image data with the same func calling.

```
int decompress_jpeg(char **dest, 
                int *size, 
                int *width, 
                int *height, 
                int *bpp, 
                char *src, 
                int src_size,
                int frac)
{
  FILE *in = fmemopen(src, src_size, "rb");
  JSAMPLE **buff;
  int bytespp;
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

  if (frac != 1 && frac != 2 && frac != 4) {
    frac = 1;
    // THODO warning
  }

  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
  jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, in);
  jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
....
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a variable named "image" to decompress_jpeg, but you read the jpeg file into "image_jpeg".

Comment: oops, that was a typo but tis not an issue..  the error is coming with image_jpeg only..

Comment: Well, the rest of what you're doing looks fine to me. (Though I did not know about fmemopen and I'd probably have used a custom source for that.)

Comment: @VincentPovirk [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html). Relatively new function.